# Getting an error with referrer: Global symbol requires explicit package name

Tags: html, perl

```
my $refer = $ENV{HTTP_REFERER};
my $gk1 = substr($str1, -4); 
if ($gk1 = .swf) { my $antigk = "gk detected"; } 
else 
    { my $antigk = $link; }
```

What is wrong with this code? I get some errors after editing it.

Could it be because of this line?

```
my $antigk
```

---

```
THIS is my new error:
Software error:

Global symbol "$str1" requires explicit package name at index_dl.pm line 680.
syntax error at index_dl.pm line 682, near "= ."
syntax error at index_dl.pm line 683, near "else"
Global symbol "$antigk" requires explicit package name at index_dl.pm line 684.
Global symbol "$direct_link" requires explicit package name at index_dl.pm line 684.
syntax error at index_dl.pm line 727, near "}"
Can't use global @_ in "my" at index_dl.pm line 731, near "= @_"
syntax error at index_dl.pm line 735, near "}"
syntax error at index_dl.pm line 761, near "}"
syntax error at index_dl.pm line 779, near "}"
index_dl.pm has too many errors.
For help, please send mail to this site's webmaster, giving this error message and the time and date of the error.

Status: 500 Content-type: text/html
Software error:

[Wed Oct  2 20:40:40 2013] fast_index_dl.cgi: Global symbol "$str1" requires explicit package name at index_dl.pm line 680.
[Wed Oct  2 20:40:40 2013] fast_index_dl.cgi: syntax error at index_dl.pm line 682, near "= ."
[Wed Oct  2 20:40:40 2013] fast_index_dl.cgi: syntax error at index_dl.pm line 683, near "else"
[Wed Oct  2 20:40:40 2013] fast_index_dl.cgi: Global symbol "$antigk" requires explicit package name at index_dl.pm line 684.
[Wed Oct  2 20:40:40 2013] fast_index_dl.cgi: Global symbol "$direct_link" requires explicit package name at index_dl.pm line 684.
[Wed Oct  2 20:40:40 2013] fast_index_dl.cgi: syntax error at index_dl.pm line 727, near "}"
[Wed Oct  2 20:40:40 2013] fast_index_dl.cgi: Can't use global @_ in "my" at index_dl.pm line 731, near "= @_"
[Wed Oct  2 20:40:40 2013] fast_index_dl.cgi: syntax error at index_dl.pm line 735, near "}"
[Wed Oct  2 20:40:40 2013] fast_index_dl.cgi: syntax error at index_dl.pm line 761, near "}"
[Wed Oct  2 20:40:40 2013] fast_index_dl.cgi: syntax error at index_dl.pm line 779, near "}"
[Wed Oct  2 20:40:40 2013] fast_index_dl.cgi: index_dl.pm has too many errors.
Compilation failed in require at ./fast_index_dl.cgi line 53.
For help, please send mail to this site's webmaster, giving this error message and the time and date of the error.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have this near the top of your `index_dl.pm` file:

```
use strict;
```

This means that you need to declare each variable with `my` before you use it:

```
my $str1;
```

You probably want to declare `$antigk` before your `if-else` block, and maybe you really want:

```
my $antigk = $link;
if ($gk1 eq '.swf') { $antigk = "gk detected"; } 
else 
{ $antigk = $link; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# In this line you store the HTTP referer in the variable $refer
my $refer = $ENV{HTTP_REFERER};

# Then, in this link you take a substring of the variable $str1.
# But you don't have a variable called $str1.
# Perhaps you actually wanted to take a substring of $refer?
my $gk1 = substr($str1, -4); 

# This next line will be a syntax error because you need to quote
# strings (and .swf is a string. This should be '.swf'.
# Also, you are using '='. This is the assignment operator. This
# will set $pgk1 to the value '.swf'. That's not what you want to do.
# You want to compare $pgk1 and '.swf'. For that you need the comparison
# operator - which is 'eq'.
# So this whole line should be:
# if ($gk1 eq '.swf') {
if ($gk1 = .swf) {
  # It's good that you are declaring $antigk using 'my'. But 'my' only
  # works within a code block. So you're setting $antigk here, but the
  # value will be lost as soon as you pass the end of the code block
  # (which is the '}' on the very next line).
  # Better to declare $antigk (with 'my $antigk') before the 'if' statement.
  my $antigk = "gk detected";
} else {
  my $antigk = $link;
}
```

In general, you are making some very basic programming errors here. I assume that you think you learn best by jumping into a problem and Googling for help. I don't think that approach is working for you. I'd strongly recommend talking a couple of days to work through a beginner Perl book (like "Learning Perl") before continuing with this project.

Answer (score 0):

Apart of toolic's answer, I guess you have to change those lines:

```
my $refer = $ENV{HTTP_REFERER};
my $gk1 = substr($str1, -4);
```

to these ones:

```
my $refer = $ENV{HTTP_REFERER};
my $gk1   = substr($refer, -4); 
#                  ^^^^^^
```